# JQuery image slide right to left and vice versa

Tags: jquery

I have a div with some images inside and i want to have 3 of them visible at all time but when i am clicking the move to left button i want to appear the next image from right side and when clicking right button to appear the first from left. Sample code here.

```
<div id="goLeft">Left</div>
<div id="images">
   <img id="img1" width="80" height="60" src="1.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img2" width="80" height="60" src="2.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img3" width="80" height="60" src="3.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img4" width="80" height="60" src="4.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img5" width="80" height="60" src="5.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img6" width="80" height="60" src="6.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img7" width="80" height="60" src="7.jpg "></img>
</div>
<div id="goRight">Right</div>
```

Any idea?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Have you even tried googling?

Comment: ofc i did but i found nothing

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=jquery+image+slider&oq=jquery+image+slider&aqs=chrome..69i57.9208j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Maybe i did not make my self clear. I do not want to change images in a slideshow. I have a div with images inside and 3 of them are always visible, display:inline-block. Now i want when i am clicking the right button all images go to left and appear hide the first from left image and appear the next from right.

Comment: you can set this in any plugin options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you have troubles finding a suitable plugin. But if this is all you need from the image slider? then you  can use this as an example:

**HTML**

I've changed your markup a bit in order to fit the task( added `<div id="container">`)

```
<div id="goLeft">Left</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="images">
   <img id="img1" width="80" height="60" src="1.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img2" width="80" height="60" src="2.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img3" width="80" height="60" src="3.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img4" width="80" height="60" src="4.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img5" width="80" height="60" src="5.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img6" width="80" height="60" src="6.jpg "></img>
   <img id="img7" width="80" height="60" src="7.jpg "></img>
</div>
</div>
<div id="goRight">Right</div>
```

**CSS**

1) the container div is set width of 3 images +  margins between them(5px) 
2) The height must be as the height of the image;
3) `overflow:hidden` - hides the scrollbar;
4) Width for image div is set in order to fit all images inline;

```
#container
        {
            width:250px;
            height:60px;
                overflow:hidden;
        }

#images
        {
            width:9999px;
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
var margin = 0;
var max_margin =  ($("#images").children().length *80)-255;
$("#goLeft").click(function(){
    if(margin > -max_margin){
        margin = margin - 84;
    $("#images").css("margin-left",margin+"px");
    }
});
$("#goRight").click(function(){
    if(margin <0){
         margin = margin + 84;
    $("#images").css("margin-left",margin+"px");
    }
});
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2Lm9/1/)